# Can't use react-bootstrap <Button>

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I installed `react-bootstrap` with `npm`, then I tried to render a `<Button variant="primary">` on the page, but instead I get this error:

```
dispatcher is null
useContext@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43381:7
useBootstrapPrefix@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40752:56
../../node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Button.js/Button<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40670:84
renderWithHooks@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:21292:31
updateForwardRef@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:23863:24
beginWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:25910:20
callCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10884:18
invokeGuardedCallbackDev@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10928:20
invokeGuardedCallback@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:10985:35
beginWork$1@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30859:32
performUnitOfWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30106:16
workLoopSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30029:26
renderRootSync@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:30002:11
performConcurrentWorkOnRoot@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:29396:78
workLoop@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37423:46
flushWork@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37401:18
performWorkUntilDeadline@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37638:25
```

Here is my code...

**Component:**

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function AddToCart(){
  return (
    <Button variant="primary">Add To Cart</Button> //doesnt work, but other tags work
  );
}

export default AddToCart
```

**index.js:**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import AddToCart from './components/AddToCart.js';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <AddToCart /> 
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();
```

**index.html:**

```
<div class="col-3 text-center">
    <img src="./images/WavSupply-Sidepce-Elysium-Loop-Kit-920x920.jpg">
    <h4>PRODUCT</h4>
    <p>$50.00</p>
    <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to render other non-bootstrap tags instead of `<Button>` and they render just fine, I'm also almost sure `react-bootstrap` is getting `imported` because I get no error messages regarding that.

Comment: Try `import {Button} from 'react-bootstrap';`, just in case it's a module mismatch thing?

Comment: Tried that, got a new error:


```Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.```

and another one:
```export 'Button' (imported as 'Button') was not found in 'react-bootstrap/Button' (possible exports: default)```

Comment: Try it again exactly as AKX put it. You still have the `/Button` on the end

Comment: Ok, fixed that but still get the same errors.

I got a ```warning``` also:

```Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.```

Comment: ... Also:

```The above error occurred in the <Button> component:

../../node_modules/react-bootstrap/esm/Button.js/Button<@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40669:7
AddToCart

Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.
Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.```